# Unique page http to https redirect by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

I've got this code in .htaccess now:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.          [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   (.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)          http://www.%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now I need my cgi script cgi-bin/test.cgi redirected to https://www.example.com/cgi-bin/test.cgi

I've already tried

```
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/test.cgi$ https://www.example.com/cgi-bin/test.cgi [L]
```

and some more other variation  but it doesn't work

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/test.cgi$ https://www.example.com/cgi-bin/test.cgi [L,R]
```

Comment: ok, now I've got

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.          [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   (.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)          http://www.%1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/test.cgi$ https://www.example.com/cgi-bin/test.cgi [L,R]

I've tried this before, doesn't work, don't understand why

Comment: You may want to change the `[L,R]` to `[L,R=301]`. Also it would be really nice to know what exactly you mean by “doesn't work”.